# How to open/close trade when price is a specific percentage distance away from the exponential moving average? (Pine)

Tags: pine-script, trading

I want to build a strategy in Pine with one exponential moving average (say 14), that opens and closes a trade if the price crosses over or under the ema. 
On top of that i want it to also open/close a trade if the price moves a certain distance away from the ema, for example 30%.

A scenario could be that the price moves 20% up on one bar but it is 30% away from the ema because of a series of bullish bars. In this case i want the code to initiate a trade that closes the posision.

And in a bearish move i want it to open a position if the price falls 30% from the ema.

Otherwise follow the rules sett by the ema.

I am a newbie and would love some help on how to do that. This is how far I have come:

Edit: and I guess there has to be a condition for the price to be over or under the ema to open or close a position if the price moves 30%, so that it doesn't accidentally close and then opens a position in the case of two bars more than 30% away from the ema.

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Moving Average Exponential", shorttitle="EMA", overlay=true, max_bars_back=1000)
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)


// Only trade from the long side
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)

// Submit orders
if (crossover(close, out))
    strategy.entry(id="Entry", long=true)

if (crossunder(close, out))
    strategy.entry(id="Close", long=false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the distance between two observations (price and EMA) as a percentage you need the following code

```
pd = (close - EMA)/EMA * 100
```

This give

```
if pd > 30
    strategy.entry(id="Entry", long=true)

if pd < 30
    strategy.entry(id="Close", long=false)
```